# Error building android app with Cordova 6.0.0

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

Just updated Cordova for the latest version, 6.0.0, and updated my npm for their latest stable version, 3.7.3, but keep having the same error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> *What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
> >
> > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:+.
> >          Searched in the following locations:
> >
> > https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
> >
> > https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
> >
> > Required by:
> >
> > :android:unspecified

I'm trying to build with the recommended version of the android platform (5.1.0) and all the plugins are updated too.

Can't figure out what *:_debugCompile* is and how to fix this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by removing [this plugin](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim). Apparently this is what's been making the error.